# Can you render only <%-body%> tag in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, render

is there a way to render only the <%-body%> in ejs? I have a sidebar(with animation) in my layout and when i click every link in the sidebar it refresh the whole page and the animation of the sidebar.

can you only change the body without refreshing the page?

Comment: You'd have to have different elements in the HTML page that appear when one of those links are clicked. You cannot render a separate file without refreshing the page.

Comment: @Tyler2P please explain it further, im a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of what you'd have to do to switch the current page in HTML.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-1">
        <!-- First page -->
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-2">
        <!-- Second page -->
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let wrapper1 = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper-1");
    let wrapper2 = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper-2");
    function linkClicked(event) {
        // Check which link was clicked

        // Hide wrapper1 and show wrapper2
        wrapper1.style.display = 'none';
        wrapper2.style.display = 'unset';
    }
    document.querySelector('HTML class/ID of a button').addEventListener('click', linkClicked, false);
<script>
</html>
```